# странное поведение обученной модели CNTK на gpu и cpu при валидации

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

После обучения модели с использование CNTK я начал проверять её и заметил что при проверке с использование cpu и gpu при подаче одних и тех же данных результаты сильно отличаются:
проверка на GPU

```
Selected GPU[0] GeForce GTX 1070 Ti as the process wide default device.
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\13_12_.jpg -----> [[ 0.9101731 -0.6508888]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\1_0_.jpg -----> [[ 0.92789257 -0.908758  ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\22_21_.jpg -----> [[-0.9976645  0.9982569]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\27_26_.jpg -----> [[-0.998505  0.99378 ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\2_1_.jpg -----> [[-0.90199035  0.98187655]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\3_2_.jpg -----> [[ 0.74856555 -0.8233332 ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\8_7_.jpg -----> [[-0.99428606  0.99768484]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\9_8_.jpg -----> [[ 0.9414453 -0.878847 ]]

count bad--->> 4
count all--->> 8
50.0 %
```

проверка на CPU

```
Selected CPU as the process wide default device.
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\13_12_.jpg -----> [[-0.99976563  0.9996888 ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\1_0_.jpg -----> [[-0.99988014  0.9994083 ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\22_21_.jpg -----> [[-0.99997294  0.9992145 ]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\27_26_.jpg -----> [[-0.9999791  0.9990366]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\2_1_.jpg -----> [[-0.9999601   0.99890137]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\3_2_.jpg -----> [[-0.9998507  0.9994793]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\8_7_.jpg -----> [[-0.99998456  0.99857247]]
D:\test\work_temp\work_temp\image\9_8_.jpg -----> [[-0.99981445  0.99947965]]

count bad--->> 8
count all--->> 8
100.0 %
```

Верный результат дает проверка на GPU.
Когда я начал проверять в чем же дело, начал смотреть может что то  в скрипте поменял(раньше этот скрипт у меня работал я только менял архитектуру модели и все). Заметил что если в архитектуре находятся два сверточных слоя с одинаковыми размерами фильтров я как раз и получаю такое поведение. Почему это так происходит? работаю с CTNK недавно. 
Модель сети:

```
input = C.input_variable(input_dim_model)
label = C.input_variable(num_output_class)

with C.layers.default_options(activation=C.relu,pad=True):
    my_model =  C.layers.Sequential([             
                C.layers.Convolution((11, 11),32,init=C.he_uniform(),name="conv1"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),

                C.layers.Convolution((11,11),64,init=C.he_uniform(),name="conv2"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),

                C.layers.Convolution((5, 5), 96,init=C.he_uniform(),name="conv3"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),

                C.layers.Convolution((3, 3),128,init=C.he_uniform(),name="conv4"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),

                C.layers.Dense(32,activation=C.tanh,init=C.glorot_uniform(),name="dense1"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                C.layers.Dense(16,activation=C.tanh,init=C.glorot_uniform(),name="dense2"),
                C.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                C.layers.Dense(2, activation=C.tanh,init=C.glorot_uniform(),name="classify")
                ])(input/255)

C.logging.log_number_of_parameters(my_model);

minibatch_size = 128
num_minibaches_to_train =9000

loss = C.cross_entropy_with_softmax(my_model,label)
error = C.classification_error(my_model,label)

learning_rate          = 0.25
lr_shedule             = C.learning_parameter_schedule(learning_rate)

mm                     = [0.9] * 20
mm_schedule            = C.learners.momentum_schedule(mm, minibatch_size=minibatch_size)
l2_reg_weight          = 0.0025

learner =C.learners.adadelta(my_model.parameters,lr=lr_shedule,rho=0.85,epsilon=0.0001,l2_regularization_weight = l2_reg_weight)
trainer = C.Trainer(my_model,(loss,error),[learner])
```

Проверка модели:

```
import cntk as c
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

#для проверки на cpu
#c.device.try_set_default_device(c.device.cpu())
#для проверки на gpu
#c.device.try_set_default_device(c.device.gpu(0))

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"image\\")

ls = os.listdir(path)

print(len(ls))

count_all=0
count_bad=0
my_model = c.Function.load("D:\\test\\PythonApplication1\\PythonApplication1\\my_model.dnn")
out = my_model


for name in ls:
    aa = cv2.imread(path+name,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    ss = cv2.resize(aa,(64,64),cv2.INTER_AREA)
    ms = np.array(ss,dtype=np.float32)

    ms = np.reshape(ms,(1,64,64))
    count_all+=1

    m_outputData = out.eval(ms)
    if m_outputData[0][0]<=0:
        count_bad+=1


    print(path+name,"----->",m_outputData)

print("\ncount bad--->>",count_bad)
print("\ncount all--->>",count_all)
print(100.0*count_bad/count_all,"%")
```

Так же заметил что на некоторых машинах с другим процессором, все работает хорошо, а на каких то нет: мой процессор intel i7-4790, другая машина где результат правильный  intel i7-4820K